# Checking if a stream is a zip file

Tags: java, stream, zip

We have a requirement to determine whether an incoming InputStream is a reference to an zip file or zip data. We do not have reference to the underlying source of the stream. We aim to copy the contents of this stream into an OutputStream directed at an alternate location.

I tried reading the stream using ZipInputStream and extracting a ZipEntry. The ZipEntry is null if the stream is a regular file - as expected - however, in checking for a ZipEntry I loose the initial couple of bytes from the stream. Hence, by the time I know that the stream is a regular stream, I have already lost initial data from the stream.

Any thoughts around how to check if the InputStream is an archive without data loss would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see my comments to the reply by Galactus below - which is the approach I am taking as a resolution. Thanks all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't forget to mark the answer you chose as "selected" (the check mark outline on the left).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your original inputstream is not buffered, I would try wrapping the original stream in a BufferedInputStream, before wrapping that in a ZipInputStream to check. You can use "mark" and "reset" in the BufferedInputStream to return to the initial position in the stream, after your check.

Comment: Thank you. I am going 'duh!'. I am about to try this.

Comment: This works. I am able to wrap my original InputStream as a BufferedInputStream, set a mark and then create a ZipInputStream to check for a ZipEntry. A reset() call and my stream is ready for reuse. Now, experimenting with the best size for the buffer. Thanks much !

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it.

Using mark/reset to restore the stream if the GZIPInputStream detects incorrect zip format (throws the ZipException).

```
/**
 * Wraps the input stream with GZIPInputStream if needed. 
 * @param inputStream
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
private InputStream wrapIfZip(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    if (!inputStream.markSupported()) {
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    }
    inputStream.mark(1000);
    try {
        return new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
    } catch (ZipException e) {
        inputStream.reset();
        return inputStream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check first bytes of stream for ZIP local header signature (PK 0x03 0x04), that would be enough for most cases. If you need more precision, you should take last ~100 bytes and check for central directory locator fields.

Comment: Yes, this did seem to be most apparent approach for the verification of the stream. However, I understand, depending on the tool used for creating the zip, the header could differ. Hence, although the most reliable check, we moved away from this since we did not want to check for every possible pkzip header.

Comment: Please let me know if the difference in headers based on tools is not the case.

Comment: ZIP standard has a strong criteria for zip local header field, so it must have the same format for all zip archives.

Comment: I really don't know how this isn't the correct answer.  Why do so much work when you could literally check the first 4 characters?

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky, could you provide us an example code of such verification?

Comment: You are welcome to check PKWare ZIP Appnote for zip archive format.

Answer (score 1):

You have described a [java.io.PushbackInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html#unread%28byte%5b%5d%29) - in addition to `read()`, it has an `unread(byte[])` which allows you push them bck to the front of the stream, and to re-`read()` them again.

It's in `java.io` since JDK1.0 (though I admit I haven't seen a use for it until today).

Comment: I did try using the PushbackInputStream. However, the act of creating a ZipInputStream to check if the stream has a ZipEntry and is hence an archive, reads bytes in addition to the Pushback stream's read - which are lost to the unread() call.

Comment: @AKS: Wait, so you can't wrap the PBS in ZS? That kind of defeats the PBS's usefulness :(

Comment: Ten years later, I confirm that `PushbackInputStream` works for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit like a hack, but you could implement a proxy [java.io.InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) to sit between ZipInputStream and the stream you originally passed to ZipInputStream's constructor.  Your proxy would stream to a buffer until you know whether it's a ZIP file or not.  If not, then the buffer saves your day.

Comment: Yes, it does sound like a hack :) .. but an interesting one. I am about to try the suggestion by Galactus and try this one if that does not work :)